# How can I extract links and users from one column and place them in another column?

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, hyperlink, tweets

I have a column that has user information and links like this:

```
tweet
1   "¿Tienes dudas sobre #ciberseguridad y no sabes a quién acudir? Desde @INCIBE queremos recordarte que estamos a tu disposición en nuestro teléfono gratuito ☎017. ¡Te ayudaremos!
  https://www.osi.es/es/contacto  pic.twitter.com/uJ3zNQxfda"
2   Hola @ProtoMot, te recomendamos que leas el siguiente artículo de nuestra web y si sigues teniendo dudas puedes llamarnos gratuitamente al 017 la Línea de Ayuda en Ciberseguridad. https://www.osi.es/es/actualidad/blog/2019/04/04/microsoft-te-ha-llamado-sin-haberlo-solicitado …
3   "Hola @Lotharmatao2020, para atender tu consulta de forma personalizada puedes ponerte en contacto con nosotros llamando gratuitamente al 017, la Línea de Ayuda en Ciberseguridad.
 https://www.incibe.es/linea-de-ayuda-en-ciberseguridad …"
```

I want to create something that recognizes the users and the links of the rows. In such a way that I have a new column in the dataframe with this result:

```
 tweet_mentions
    1    @INCIBE
     https://www.osi.es/es/contacto  pic.twitter.com/uJ3zNQxfda"
    2 @ProtoMot
https://www.osi.es/es/actualidad/blog/2019/04/04/microsoft-te-ha-llamado-sin-haberlo-solicitado …
    3    @Lotharmatao2020
     https://www.incibe.es/linea-de-ayuda-en-ciberseguridad …"
```

I was thinking about creating a function that recognizes the @ and the https but i don´t know what´s the best way for do this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
import re

a = [
   '¿Tienes dudas sobre #ciberseguridad y no sabes a quién acudir? Desde @INCIBE queremos recordarte que estamos a tu disposición en nuestro teléfono gratuito ☎017. ¡Te ayudaremos!   https://www.osi.es/es/contacto  pic.twitter.com/uJ3zNQxfda',
   'Hola @ProtoMot, te recomendamos que leas el siguiente artículo de nuestra web y si sigues teniendo dudas puedes llamarnos gratuitamente al 017 la Línea de Ayuda en Ciberseguridad. https://www.osi.es/es/actualidad/blog/2019/04/04/microsoft-te-ha-llamado-sin-haberlo-solicitado',
   'Hola @Lotharmatao2020, para atender tu consulta de forma personalizada puedes ponerte en contacto con nosotros llamando gratuitamente al 017, la Línea de Ayuda en Ciberseguridad. https://www.incibe.es/linea-de-ayuda-en-ciberseguridad'
]

for n, s in enumerate(a):
   a_at = re.findall('@[^ ,]+', s)
   a_url = re.findall('https://[^ ,]+', s)
   print(n, a_at)
   print(a_url)
```

Note this is going to miss stuff like `pic.twitter.com/uJ3zNQxfda`, but you could say that is not a valid URL, as it's missing the protocol. If you need to match URLs with optional protocol, that will be a much more difficult regular expression.

Comment: Thank you Steven. 
But i want to put the mentions of the users and hyperlinks into a new column like the example.Do you know how can i do that ?